# Configuring Namespace Reservations on Windows XP 64 bit

Tags: deployment, windows-xp, httpcfg.exe

I need to register HTTP URL namespace to a particular group of users. On MSDN it is explained that I have to use HttpCfg.exe which appears that doesn't exists for Windows XP 64 bit.

Does anyone has an idea on how to do this?

Regards,
Mita

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is solved using http://blogs.msdn.com/paulwh/attachment/2416236.ashx application. I just add HTTP URL namespace and gave execute right to particular user.

Answer (score 1):

The zip file that @Mita posted contains a helpful project for managing namespaces, but I found the companion article more useful: PaulWh discusses the [AddressAccessDeniedException](http://blogs.msdn.com/paulwh/archive/2007/05/04/addressaccessdeniedexception-http-could-not-register-url-http-8080.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Download the Windows Server 2003 Service Pack 2 Support Tools from the Microsoft website here: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=96a35011-fd83-419d-939b-9a772ea2df90&displaylang=en

The tools are 32-bit but are supported on x64.